# How to use a list of lists as parameters for functions in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a function that will automatically calculate equivalent vectors, but I get an error.

```
def vector(lst):
 import math
 Sfy , Sfx = 0
 for i in lst:
    fy = i[0]/math.sin(i[1])
    fx = i[0]/math.cos(i[1])
    if 90 < i[1] < 180:
        fx = -1*fx
    if 180 <= i[1] <= 270:
        fx = -1*fx
        fy = -1*fy
    if 270 < i[1] < 360:
        fy = -1*fy
    print(fx , fy)
    Sfy = Sfy + fy
    Sfx = Sfx + fx
if Sfx < 0 and Sfy > 0:
    A = 90
elif Sfx < 0 and Sfy < 0:
    A = 180
elif Sfx > 0 and Sfy < 0:
    A = 270
R = math.sqrt(Sfy*Sfy + Sfx*Sfx) #R is for the finale vector force and A is for its angle
A += math.asin(R/Sfy)
print(R + "(N)<" + A)
```

vector([100 , 260] , [50 , 80])

The error is:

> vector([100 , 260] , [50 , 80])
> TypeError: vector() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I think it's because my function can not accept a list of lists, does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: You didn't pass a list of lists. You passed two lists. Also, please use consistent indentation.

Comment: Make it a single list as: `[[100, 260], [50, 80]]`.

Comment: The error message, if you read it, tells you exactly the problem. Your function is defined as taking one parameter `def vector(lst)`, and you are providing two `vector([100,260],[50,80])`

Answer (score 1):

You have inserted 2 list if you give: `vector([100 , 260] , [50 , 80])`

so actually you have passed two lists not a list of list.

For list of list you must give : `vector([[100 , 260] , [50 , 80]])`